# Ordenar una matriz de 3x3 en forma vertical u horizontal, Java

Tags: java, matriz

Pide "crear una matriz de 3x3, llenarla como cualquier número, y preguntar al usuario como quiere la salida: orden horizontal ascendente, horizontal descendente, vertical ascendente o vertical descendente. Los números se capturan por teclado."

Y esto es lo que llevo pero no se como ordenarlos :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

    int matriz [][],nFilas,nCol,oha,ohd,ova,ovd;
    nFilas=3;
    nCol=3;
    matriz=new int [nFilas][nCol];
    System.out.println("digite la mariz");
    for (int i = 0; i < nFilas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
            System.out.println("Matriz["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
            matriz[i][j]=leer.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La matriz es: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < nFilas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    String Orden;
    System.out.println("Como deseas ordenar los numeros: de modo orden horizontal acendente, horizontal desendente, vertical acendente o vertical decendente");
    Orden=leer.next();
    if(Orden.equals("horizontal acendente"));
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Luis puedes explicar qué salida esperas si el usuario elige las opciones de horizontal ascendente, horizontal descendente, vertical ascendente o vertical descendente, ya que no entiendo que esperas como resultado de esas opciones.

Answer (score 0):

Si quisiera obtener una matriz ordenada

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Tendrías que primero ordenar los valores y mostrarlos, puedes hacerlo con los métodos de ordenamiento
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de lo que yo puedo comprender acerca de tu ejercicio

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 int matriz[][] = new int[3][3];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Llenamos la matriz
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    matriz[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(" "+"\n");
}
//Ordenamos la matriz
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
                if(matriz[i][j] < matriz[x][y]){
                    int t = matriz[i][j];
                    matriz[i][j] = matriz[x][y];
                    matriz[x][y] = t;
        }
        }
    }
}}

//Ahora solo imprimela
System.out.println("--------------------"+"\n");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
}
    System.out.print(" "+"\n");
}}}
```

Nota que es para una matriz de 3x3, pero puede hacer mas modificaciones para que sea mas grande la matriz. Pero eso ya es a tu preferencia
Es por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, espero te sirva
Saludos ;-)